# Electrical turning off on its own

Tags: electrical

I have a 1938 home which was rewired with cloth covered wires.  We have changed all outlets and switches but one circuit will shut off sometimes repeatedly and sometimes will stay on for 6 hours.  This has T.V. connected to it in living room,  dining room (ceiling fan flickers), bathroom, and another bedroom.  Small house and we were only running T.V. when it does this.  Could it be a bad wire heating and cooling at that one area.  Should I have house rewired? Is this a fire hazard?

Comment: When this happens, does it trip a circuit breaker or blow a fuse? Or does it come back on by itself? Is it approximately half the house, or exactly one circuit?

Answer (score 1):

A short circuit is a fire hazard, though it may not require rewiring the house to repair. When this happens, identify all affected outlets and lights.

Then, when the circuit is normal, locate section of wire that must contain the fault by separating the line and load at various points to map out the circuit. When you disconnect the hot at one point in the circuit and turn the power back on, everything that doesn't have power is part of the load from that device, and everything still working is part of the line.

With the process of elimination, you can identify the 2 outlets where only the problem outlets are affected when the hot is disconnected, one outlet that has the problem itself, and another that doesn't have the problem. The fault will be at one of these outlets or the line between the two will need to be replaced.

Answer (score -2):

there might be a wire cracked somewhere in that circuit. It might expands because of the electricity's flow ( elector-magnetic field ) and cause the interruption.